# prop value showing [object Object] and also showing correctly in the same component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

`<span title={myProp}>{myProp}</span>`

In the above html, the `myProp` in the span displays correctly as: 03/17/2022, 1:21 PM

The `myProp` assigned to the title attribute displays as `[object Object]`.
Anyone have any idea what's happening here?

`myProp` is the value output from `<FormattedDate />` imported from `react-intl`

I've a CodeSandbox here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-https-tc1l3h

If you hover over the date in the browser you can see `[object Object]`

Comment: `[object Object]` is the default string representation of an object. So `myProp` appears to be an object and it's stringified when it's assigned to the the `title` attribute. Without knowing what you expect to happen and what `myProp` actually is we can't really tell you how to fix this.

Comment: can you show us what myProp actually is?

Comment: Sorry... I've added more detail. I'm localizing a date using react-intl

Comment: What do you mean by "displays correctly"? How does it appear in the browser?

Comment: It displays correctly as:
 03/17/2022, 1:21 PM

Comment: Please update your code with entire flow of what you are doing with FormattedDate and how you expect FormattedDate to return you anything that. This is very confusing, would be also helpful if you create Codesandbox for us to look at

Comment: I've created a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-https-tc1l3h